# Possible to have an NSIS callback function after all files were copied?

Tags: installation, nsis

Trying to optimize my MUI 2 NSIS setup in which I do some `ExecWait` calls in the [`.onInstSuccess` callback function](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.7.2.1.4), I was searching through [the documentation](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html) to find a callback that is called:

- after the files are all copied *-and-*
- before the wizard page is being switched from the file copy page to the finish page.

Unfortunately, I found no such callback.

**Therefore my question is:**

Is it possible to do some custom processing after the files are copied and before the wizard page is being switched away from the file copy page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE` is fine. It really depends on if you want the action to take place before or after "Completed" is printed in the log. For the former you can just stick the code in the last section:

```
Section
SetOutPath $Instdir
File "Foo"
File "Bar"

ExecWait '"$Instdir\dofinalthing.exe" /blah'
SectionEnd
```

or

```
Section
SetOutPath $Instdir
File "Foo"
File "Bar"
SectionEnd

Section -post
ExecWait '"$Instdir\dofinalthing.exe" /blah'
SectionEnd
```

This will of course be part of the progressbar and will print to the log unless you use `setdetailsprint`...

Comment: Great answer (as always ;-). Thanks a lot, Anders!

Answer (score 1):

Just found out the solution by myself (maybe [Anders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3501/anders) will have a better one, though):

[MUI 2](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Modern%20UI%202/Readme.html) allows to define custom callback functions so I used the [`MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE` macro](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Demonstrating_Page%27s_Custom_Functions_Pre_Show_Leave) right before the definition of

```
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
```

To register a custom function. So my NSI file looks like:

```
...
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE inst_leave
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
...
```

With `inst_leave` being something like

```
Function inst_leave
    ...
FunctionEnd
```

This did the trick.